# Can I use battery in a high voltage (600V) float circuit?

Tags: high-voltage, floating

I know this requirement is weird, but it's indeed what I need in my circuit.

A 12V acid battery powers my circuit board and connects to the signal-VCC and signal-GND.  The circuit works at high voltage bias, i.e., a high-voltage source provides the signal-GND 600V relative to the chassis ground (0V).

I worry that the 600V potential added to the battery '-' will cause danger. How about the insulation of a battery's shell? Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: To make it more transparent. The chassis-ground is 0V, the signal-ground is 600V, the signal-VCC is 612V. This is designed for a nuclide activity measurement system, which requires a high voltage to generate an ionization current.

Comment: Strictly by itself, only adding 600 V to all the circuit nodes won't cause the circuit behavior to change or the battery to have problems. So this isn't a circuit question but an environmental one. We'd probably need to know a lot more about the setup for making those measurements. I'm not familiar with that application space, but I assume you aren't the first one doing this. What have others done successfully in the past?

Comment: You will probably not find a 12V battery rated to 600+V through the case, so you will need to put it in a (possibly) explosion-proof casing that is rated for the voltage and also resistant to sulfuric acid since any leaks will also be at 600V. Pricey.

Comment: @periblepsis My circuit is meant to replace a Keithley instrument (6517B); Someone previously floated it at 600V. But this is different because 220V AC powers 6517B, and I guess there is a transformer to isolate 600V high voltage. I still prefer to use batteries because they can provide lower noise. Unless they're hazardous.

Comment: @vir Thanks for providing this idea. I googled 'explosion-proof enclosure' and got some products that seemed like metal boxes. Do you mean these enclosures should be connected to the chassis ground to prevent leakage? (But if the battery cannot rate 600V, it still might explode.) -------- BTW, Is it possible that I use an insulated enclosure to place the batteries rather than the 'explosion-proof' one?

Comment: Explosion-proof in that context relates to electrical equipment in explosive atmospheres rather than catastrophic battery failures

Comment: The problem is hydrogen has evolved during charging. Maybe you have a sealed cell, maybe it's a gel-cell, but some lead-acid cells give off hydrogen as they charge and keeping them in a sealed container is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You’re right to worry but this situation can be managed.  You should protect/insulate all of the high-voltage (relative to ground) equipment, including the entire battery; don’t assume that the battery itself has insulation rated to more than 12V.